# primefaces extension master detail update not working along with selectDetailLevel

Tags: jsf, partial, primefaces-extensions

When I added update attribute in the commandButton within master detail component of primefaces extension the selectDetaillevel component is not excuting. When I remove the update attribute selectDetailLevel execute. Please let me know how I have excute update along with selectDetailLevel.

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{controller.save}" 
                 update=":growl"
  <pe:selectDetailLevel step="-1"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've seen similar questions elsewhere, and the gist of the problem is that the masterdetail component has to be 'updated' to work, and it is included by default as long as you don't specify other things to update. If you do, pf-ext thinks you're handling these updates manually, and doesn't auto-update the masterdetail. So, to fix it, you change your update attribute to:

`update=":growl masterdetail"`